# combinación de indicadores en editor pine tradingview

Tags: pine-script

Al realizar o meter el codigo en tradingview-editor pine tengo los siguentes problemas -todo esto es de la pagina trading view
//problemas:
//* queda muy pequeño el rsi y stocasthic y quedan el mismo cuadro o muy grande?
//*no puedo encontrar la "x" para cerrar??
//*Los dos script en el mismo no se puede uno encima del otro rsi y stocastic??
//*los colores los coloque hexagecimal por que el color.blue por ejemplo no compila??

```
    //@version=3
    study("scalping", overlay=true)
    
    //EMAS
    
    plot(ema(close, 100), color=#FF7F00, linewidth=2, title=' EMA 100')
    plot(ema(close, 200), color=#00FFFF, linewidth=3, title='EMA 200')
    
    //banda de bollinger
    shorttitle="BB", title="Bollinger Bands", overlay=true, resolution=""
    length = input(20, minval=1)
    src = input(close, title="Source")
    mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
    basis = sma(src, length)
    dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
    upper = basis + dev
    lower = basis - dev
    plot(basis, color=#FF0000)
    p1 = plot(upper, color=#FFFFFF)
    p2 = plot(lower, color=#FFFFFF)
    fill(p1, p2)
    
    
    
    // RSI
    srcRSI = close, lenRSI = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
    up = rma(max(change(srcRSI), 0), lenRSI)
    down = rma(-min(change(srcRSI), 0), lenRSI)
    rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
    plot(rsi, color=#9C27B0)
    bandRSI1 = hline(70)
    bandRSI0 = hline(30)
    fill(bandRSI1, bandRSI0, color=#9C27B0, transp=90)
    // FIN RSI
    
    
    
    //Stochastic
    
    periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)
    periodD = input(3, title="D", minval=1)
    smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
    k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
    d = sma(k, periodD)
    plot(k, title="%K", color=#2196F3)
    plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF7F00)
    h0 = hline(80)
    h1 = hline(20)
    fill(h0, h1, color=#9C27B0, transp=75)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu imágen no se subió, intenta editar la pregunta.

Comment: perfecto la imagen ya esta.gracias

Answer (score 0):

Luego de más de un año seguramente ya habrás resuelto la duda, en todo caso dejo esta respuesta por si otra persona tiene la misma, a para mí también fue un problema lo que describes.

**El primer problema** es la escala de la gráfica, los indicadores tienen una escala de `0` a `100`, mientras que el precio de las velas se aprecia tienen una escala inferior a `1`.
La forma de evitar esto es usar `overlay=false` en el encabezado. Debes cerrar el indicador y agregarlo nueva mente para refrescar.

**El segundo problema** puedes cerrar el indicador identificando la correctamente la cruz de cierre.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tercer**, No es claro lo de poner un indicador sobre otro, pues a simple vista ya están superpuestos.

**Cuarto**, la forma `color.red` es correcta en la versión 4, en la versión 3 como dice la [documentación: color](https://es.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v3/#fun_color) sería `color(red, 0)` o simplemente `red`.